# Angular 4 Reactive forms - FormArray of FormArrays

Tags: angular, recursion, angular-reactive-forms

I'd like to ask you about reactive forms. 
I am trying to create view for my form object.

In my controller I have form like that because I would like to give the user possibilty to create as many inputs as he wants. First of all I was trying to create only array of arrays without wrapping group, but I had errors that it is impossible. So I have group, inside group I have array that contains controls or sub arrays.

My controller:

```
    createForm() {
    this.simpleGroup = this.fb.group({
        simpleArray: this.fb.array([
                this.fb.control('1a'),
                this.fb.control('1b'),
                this.fb.array([
                    this.fb.control('2a'),
                    this.fb.control('2b')
                ])
            ]
        )
    });
}
```

And view:

```
<form [formGroup]="simpleGroup" novalidate>
<div formArrayName="simpleArray" class="well well-lg">
    <div *ngFor="let arrayElement of simpleArray.controls; let i=index">

        <div *ngIf="arrayElement.length == null">
            <input type="text" [formControlName]="i">
        </div>

        <div *ngIf="arrayElement.length != null">
            <!--TODO:-->
            <div formArrayName="?">
                <div *ngFor="let subArrayElement of ...; let i = index">
                    <input type="text">
                    <input type="text">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--END TODO:-->
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Inside loop I have two divs first displayed if element of table is the control. Second will be displayed if it is not control but an array. Inside second div should be two inputs for controls of that subarray but I have a lot of error that form array must have group as a parent etc. I am not sure is form object correct but I think it is not a solution to wrap subarray in another group.

Thanks for help

Comment: Do you have any metadata regarding the fields that are to be added dynamically by the client? By metadata, I mean what input you’re expecting: a phone numbers array, an email text field?

Comment: Yes, I have creator of inputs where user specify how that input looks like.

Comment: So you're gonna have multiple buttons to add different types of inputs. On each of those buttons, you can tie different events and you can add correct type of control to your simpleArray. `this.simpleGroup.get('simepleArray')` then use `addControl`. You do need to subscribe to valueChanges somewhere to catch these changes so you can reference the right thing, especially the dynamically added FormArray to your `simpleArray`

Comment: Is there a function addControl? In my code I had push function. And can you show me example how to add correct type of control to simpleArray?

Comment: I’ll construct a stackblitz but might be later